# PHP+PSR7: getParsedBody() always convert empty strings on json to null

Tags: php, zend-framework, psr-7

I'm im using `zendframework/zend-diactoros` with Laravel. I have a problem when I sent json data like

```
{
    "data": {
        "value": ""
    }
}
```

Then, in controller

```
// @var $request Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface
var_dump($request->getParsedBody())
/*
array:1 [
  "data" => array:1 [
      "value" => null // I expect "value" => ""
  ]
]
```

More examples:

I sent

```
{
    "data": {
        "value": null
    }
}
```

var_dump

```
var_dump($request->getParsedBody())
/*
array:1 [
  "data" => array:1 [
      "value" => null // that's OK
  ]
]
```

I sent

```
{
    "data": {
        "value": "x"
    }
}
```

var_dump

```
var_dump($request->getParsedBody())
/*
array:1 [
  "data" => array:1 [
      "value" => "x"  // that's OK
  ]
]
```

Only first example has a problem, but I dont have any idea if this is correct. Maybe exists a way to dump exact received data with this PSR7 library.

Comment: You should provide some *valid* example JSON that reproduces the issue. What you have provided is not at all parseable JSON.

Comment: sorry @Sammitch, json expamples updated (I forgot do it when simplify the example).